# How to test in genshi if get parameter is set?

Tags: parameters, get, trac, genshi

Is there way to test in genshi that certain get url parameter is set?

There seems to be no documentation to this.

I just need to render in template error message if there is parameter error in url.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Genshi is just the XHTML rendering engine behind Trac.

It would make sense to evaluate your GET request attributes in the [IRequestHandler](http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracDev/PluginDevelopment/ExtensionPoints/trac.web.api.IRequestHandler), that is preparing/providing data and template and passing on both for rendering and submission to the requesting client.

Furthermore use *add_notice* or *add_warning* from *trac.web.chrome* to present messages in Trac-like styling (the least intrusive way) to the user.